# Send a file located in Firebase Cloud Storage to a another website

Tags: node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-storage, form-data

I have been trying this so much time, and I don't find any good tutorial.

I'm trying to send a file located in Google Cloud Storage, using Cloud Functions, with the trigger `onFinalize` of Cloud Storage, with axios.
The problem is to append the file into the `formData`.

First I did it with my own Backend using NodeJS and Express, and it works. But I was using also Multer, but I don't know if I can use Multer here, in a Cloud Storage Trigger, or if doing that has any sense.

```js
function to(promise) {
  return promise.then(data => {
    return [null, data];
  })
    .catch(err => [err]);
}


exports.onUploadFileDetectAndCreateCorrectAction = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
  const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
  const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.

  // Get the file name.
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
  const metadata = {
    contentType: contentType,
  };

  let targetFile = bucket.file(filePath);
  let [error, dataDown] = await to(bucket.file(filePath).download({ destination: tempFilePath }));
  if (error) throw new Error('Error al descargar archivo al tmpFilePath: ', error);

  fs.readFile(tempFilePath, async (error, dataBuffer) => {
    if (error) console.log("Error al pedir e lbuffer:", dataBuffer);
    log("Data Buffer: ", dataBuffer);
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append("title", "2");
    formData.append("cover", dataBuffer, 'primerImagen');

    const response = await axios.post('https://api...', formData, {
      headers: {
        ...formData.getHeaders(),
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      }
    });
  })

});
```

I am logging the `dataBuffer`, and I see that is correct because the size is the size of the image that I upload, but the `formData` still fails.

The error I get is:

> Error: Request failed with status code 415
> at createError (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
> at settle (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
> at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
> at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:506:15)
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

I tried with `createReadStream`, a method mentioned in the File API of [CloudStorage](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html). The problem is that the File from CloudStorage doesn't have a method called buffer as the files when you work with multer in express:

```js
  formData.append("cover", bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream(), fileName);
```

Also tried to pass the Buffer with `fs.createReadStream` and `readFile`:

```js
  formData.append("cover", fs.createReadStream(filePath), fileName);
  formData.append("cover", fs.readFile(filePath), fileName);
```

But also is not working.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? 415 HTTP status means Unsupported Media Type. It indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format. I would try to check that the request header in the network (inspect/network in your browser) is the same as the content-type of the response header.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I just change my approach, so no, i didnt solve this. I create a BackEnd by my own with NodeJS and Express, just to manage files for my app. Its working all right! So, i dont use Firebase Functions for this solution.

Comment: If the issue is solved, can you post your solution as an answer and mark it as such so that other users can see it? Thank you!